# Issue when opening an application from any file type

Tags: android, file, intentfilter, samsung-mobile

I am developing an Android application where i set on manifest the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

When i open a file from "my files" Samsung app on 4.1.2 android version it doesnt work. However it works on 4.2.2 android version.

Any idea??

Thanks!